# how to move UILabel with slider in vertical

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel, uislider

i will like to move my slider together with my thumb image in vertical. However the moving was wrong.

in horizontal it works perfectly but not vertically

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
 self.SDSlider.transform = trans;
}

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.SDlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)sender.value];

    CGRect trackRect = [self.SDSlider trackRectForBounds:self.SDSlider.bounds];
    CGRect thumbRect = [self.SDSlider thumbRectForBounds:self.SDSlider.bounds
                                             trackRect:trackRect
                                                 value:self.SDSlider.value];

    self.testSDlabel.center = CGPointMake(thumbRect.origin.x + self.SDSlider.frame.origin.x,  self.SDSlider.frame.origin.y - 20);
    self.testSDlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", self.SDSlider.value];  
}
```

the label shifting from left to right instead of botton to up

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong? What do you see?

Comment: @rdelmar please see my attached images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got is working by changing the center.y value

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.SDlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)sender.value];


    CGRect trackRect = [self.SDSlider trackRectForBounds:self.SDSlider.bounds];
    CGRect thumbRect = [self.SDSlider thumbRectForBounds:self.SDSlider.bounds
                                             trackRect:trackRect
                                                 value:self.SDSlider.value];

    self.SDlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", self.SDSlider.value];

    NSLog(@"thumbRect.origin.x %f",thumbRect.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"self.testSDlabel %f",self.SDlabel.center.x);    
    self.SDlabel.center = CGPointMake(self.SDlabel.center.x, 423 - thumbRect.origin.x);

}
```

Comment: This basically got me where I needed to be to attach to a horizontal slider also

Answer (score 1):

First set the initial center of label in viewdidLoad as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initialLabelCenter = labelSliderValue.center.x
    }

    //Set value of slider into label from 100 to 1000
    @IBAction func sliderActionValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(sender.value)
        labelSliderValue.text = String(describing: currentValue)

        //Returns the drawing rectangle for the slider’s track
        let trackRect = sliderInstance.trackRect(forBounds: sliderInstance.bounds)

        //Returns the drawing rectangle for the slider’s thumb image.
        let sliderThumbRect = sliderInstance.thumbRect(forBounds: sliderInstance.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: sliderInstance.value)

        //Set label's center to move in a particular direction. In this case it will move left to right horizontally
        labelSliderValue.center = CGPoint(x: initialLabelCenter + sliderThumbRect.origin.x, y: self.labelSliderValue.center.y)
    }
```

NOTE: This code moves the label from left to right horizontally.